# The string1 outlet from the OptionalListViewController to the UILabel is invalid. Outlets can not be connected to repeating content

Tags: swift

***Help with the error*** "**The string1 outlet from the OptionalListViewController to the UILabel is invalid. Outlets can not be connected to repeating content.**"

**Code:**

```
@IBOutlet var string1: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var string2: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var string3: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var string4: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var string5: UILabel!

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:
    NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)


        let dic:NSDictionary = _items.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
        print(" Plist:\(dic)")

        let str0:NSString = dic["0"]! as! NSString
        let str1:NSString = dic["1"]! as! NSString
        let str2:NSString = dic["2"]! as! NSString
        let str3:NSString = dic["3"]! as! NSString
        let str4:NSString = dic["4"]! as! NSString
        let str5:NSString = dic["5"]! as! NSString
        let str6:NSString = dic["6"]! as! NSString
        let str7:NSString = dic["7"]! as! NSString
        let str8:NSString = dic["8"]! as! NSString

        string1.text = (str0 as String) + (str1 as String)
        string2.text = (str2 as String) + (str3 as String)
        string3.text = (str4 as String) + (str5 as String)
        string4.text = (str6 as String) + (str7 as String)
        string5.text = (str4 as String) + (str8 as String)

        return cell
}
```

***I do not understand how to fix..***

Comment: Create a custom cell and connect the outlets to it

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect an IBOutlet to a cell in a tableView on the storyboard like you have. You need to instead create a new UITableViewCell subclass and design your cell if you want to connect outlets. Make sure to check the option to create a .xib file

[image]

You can add your labels to this xib just like your view controller storyboard, and connect them to the custom cell code, rather than your view controller code (xib is an interface builder file).Here's what it looks like.. very similar to your view controller storyboard: 
[image]

Then, you can use your custom cell just like you would a normal cell, you just use your custom class instead of UITableViewCell.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:
    NSIndexPath) -> MyTableViewCell {


        let cell:MyTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)


        let dic:NSDictionary = _items.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
        print(" Plist:\(dic)")

        let str0:NSString = dic["0"]! as! NSString
        let str1:NSString = dic["1"]! as! NSString
        let str2:NSString = dic["2"]! as! NSString
        let str3:NSString = dic["3"]! as! NSString
        let str4:NSString = dic["4"]! as! NSString
        let str5:NSString = dic["5"]! as! NSString
        let str6:NSString = dic["6"]! as! NSString
        let str7:NSString = dic["7"]! as! NSString
        let str8:NSString = dic["8"]! as! NSString

        string1.text = (str0 as String) + (str1 as String)
        string2.text = (str2 as String) + (str3 as String)
        string3.text = (str4 as String) + (str5 as String)
        string4.text = (str6 as String) + (str7 as String)
        string5.text = (str4 as String) + (str8 as String)

        return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding . I did everything as you wrote - added more and error "Can not convert value of type 'UITableViewCell' to specified type 'MedicamentTableViewCell'" in the line "let cell: MedicamentTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier (" Cell ", forIndexPath: indexPath)"
Possible to fix it I will succeed !

Comment: Your version fixes bugs - not eliminate it . It took a whole day to figure it out - thank you for the effort - I'll look for another way out ..

Comment: You responded with errors in lines of code that you didn't post here. Not sure how I'm supposed to help with that =] What bugs still remain?

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic cell types:

In your storyboard tableview, choose dynamic prototype cells and add at least one prototype cell depending on how many you need to customize. 
[image: Adding prototype cell to table view]

Now your tableview should go from 0 cells in your tableview to at least one prototype cell.[image: Example tableview with one prototype cell]
 What you have done here is told the tableview to keep dequeueing a version of this cell for each call to cellForRowAtIndexPath instead of just using static cells for which you would define each and eat bunch of memory in a large tableview list.

Now select that prototype cell and give it a reuse identifier.
[image: Here I the reuse identifier is "teamCell"]

Design it. You can see mine has a couple simple image views and labels

Create a subclass for it in code with the iboutlets and connect them to your designed cell outlets. The key here, and I think the real answer to your whole question is to select the prototype cell, go to the outlet tab, and drag and drop where you see the properties listed to the cell instead of your view controller or tableview:

[image]

[image: Subclass with connected IBOutlets]

Select the prototype cell (Currently a UITableViewCell) and set its class to your UITableViewCell subclass.

[image: Set subclass]

Make sure you dequeue the correct cell in the cellForRow method.

[image: Dequeing cell]

Before all of this make sure you have thought up a good data structure for your tableview because you will need to be able to maintain its state everytime the tableview is scrolled and dequeues a cell.

Comment: Do not go out to fix it. I use a dynamic type of cells ! Class A subclass found . What I have done wrong ? All IBOutlets prototype connected to the cell .
I do not quite understand what you mean "Give the one that pops up a reuse identifier. Design it." "Make sure you dequeue the correct cell in the cellForRow method." Thanks in advance!

Comment: No problem. See above, let me know if you need further detail.

Comment: Help please still here ( Continued) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846638/nill-when-assigning-data-label-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optio