# nill when assigning data label (unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value)

Tags: swift

The first part of the code [The string1 outlet from the OptionalListViewController to the UILabel is invalid. Outlets can not be connected to repeating content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32784849/the-string1-outlet-from-the-optionallistviewcontroller-to-the-uilabel-is-invalid)

```
import UIKit

class ListsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()
       // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
       // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var string1: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var string2: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var string3: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var string4: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var string5: UILabel!

}
```

---

```
var cellyItem = ListsTableViewCell()

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:
    NSIndexPath) -> ListsTableViewCell {


        let cell:ListsTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Celly", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ListsTableViewCell


        let dic:NSDictionary = _items.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
        print(" Plist:\(dic)")

        let str0:NSString = dic["0"]! as! NSString
        let str1:NSString = dic["1"]! as! NSString
        let str2:NSString = dic["2"]! as! NSString
        let str3:NSString = dic["3"]! as! NSString
        let str4:NSString = dic["4"]! as! NSString
        let str5:NSString = dic["5"]! as! NSString
        let str6:NSString = dic["6"]! as! NSString
        let str7:NSString = dic["7"]! as! NSString
        let str8:NSString = dic["8"]! as! NSString

        cellyItem.string1.text = (str0 as String) + (str1 as String)
        cellyItem.string2.text = (str2 as String) + (str3 as String)
        cellyItem.string3.text = (str4 as String) + (str5 as String)
        cellyItem.string4.text = (str6 as String) + (str7 as String)
        cellyItem.string5.text = (str4 as String) + (str8 as String)

        return cell
}
```

cellyItem.string1,2,3,4,5 - receive nill

Why is this happening? Like all right! This "str0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8" receive data . Maybe I need to initialize the subclass ?

Comment: First thing to do: replace every forced-unwrapped value (`!`) with safe-unwrapping (`if let`), and `else` branches to handle errors.

Comment: Also: [edit] your question so that it has proper code layout (indented 4 spaces), and remove that useless text at the top.

Comment: Why do you convert to NSString and then convert to String? You can convert straight to String.

Comment: Vick below is correct. The answer to the question is that if you have set up everything correctly from the other post I made you don't need to instantiate a Celly subclass outside your cellForRow call, just use the dequeued cell.. Also some good suggestions above about formatting but as always get it functional first

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i cant comment yet, but what i noticed is very strange: why do you use cellyItem? You should just use your dequed cell everywhere. Like:

cell.string1.text = str0 + str1, etc...

Comment: Was posting exactly that: How is that supposed to work? Even if it didn't crash, you would be storing the strings into a cell that isn't used by anyone. But it crashes, because the constructor doesn't set up the IBOutlets; that's done when the cell is loaded from the storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for help - the answer was quite simple . Nill obtained because it was not created tableview. The solution was the creation of a line 
" tableView.registerNib (UINib (nibName: "ListsTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Celly") "